# CSS transition is applying when given height as max-content

Tags: css

I have added `height: max-content` to the container to set the height automatically in landscape mode
but because of that transition effect is failing.

```
.container {
        height: max-content !important;
        max-height: 90% !important;
        transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using `max-content` for the height and `90%` for max-height. When using CSS transitions, the element's height needs to be explicitly defined for the transition to take effect. Transitioning from an undefined height can cause unexpected behavior.

You have two options here. Option 1 is using js to read the height of content inside and binding it to the height of `container`.
Option 2 is much simpler, using only css. You can set `max-height` to something bigger than your `container` will ever get.

```
.container {
  height: max-content !important;
  max-height: 1000px !important;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```